# Как решить проблему с иероглифами в выходных данных в VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил расширение Code Runner. Проблему с иероглифами решить не получается.

Comment: Там скорее всего написано что-то вроде "node не является внутренней или внешней командой" и т.д. Как исправить - установить node или прописать его в переменную окружения PATH.

Comment: Работать под *nix :)

Answer (score 2):

По нормальному кажется никак, если бы это был bat файл, то можно вставить в начало что-то вроде `chcp 65001` или `chcp 437`, но это также переключит и язык вывода сообщений от консоли.

Но лучше поменять вывод на терминал, т.е. добавить в настройках VS Code параметр настройки Code Runner: `"code-runner.runInTerminal": true`, тогда при запуске будет использоваться именно терминал и потому применяются его системные настройки, и весь вывод будет так как он и должен быть. Если надо чтобы побыстрее запускалось, то смените дефолтный PS на CMD: `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"`

Необязательно это прям в файле настроек делать, просто в строке поиска параметров вводите название и появится этот пункт с подсказкой.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить на компьютер nodejs (https://nodejs.org/ru/)
После установки, плагин Code Runner стал работать корректно.

Answer (score 0):

При первом запуске кода js с помощью code runner в Visual Studio были иероглифы в выходных данных (он же Output)
Проблему решила установка Node.js (скачать можно отсюда https://nodejs.org/ru/) и последующая перезагрузка системы.